# nodejs-async: How to use a loop containing an asynchronous call within an "async.series" function block

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

While using an `async.series` based design, I have to use a loop within a function block as shown below:

```
var someFile = filePath;
async.series([
    function(cb) {
         _.forEach (
               someDataList,
               function (item) {
                   //call that executes out of sync
                   writeToFile(someFile,item)
                   //how to provide callback here
                   cb(); //<- is this correct - won't this take control out of this block in the very first loop iteration?
               }
         );
    }
],
//callback function
function (err) {...}
);
```

Comment: you need to complete the loop and go to the next function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use forEachSeries instead.

```
var someFile = filePath;
async.forEachSeries(someDataList, function(item, cb) {
   writeToFile(someFile, item)
   cb();
},
//callback function
function () {...}
);
```

**Updated after comment:**

Unfortunately there is no way of getting index of iteratee in forEachSeries. if you want index of iteratee, you can use eachOfSeries

```
var someFile = filePath;
async.eachOfSeries(someDataList, function(value, key, callback) {
    //Do something with key
    writeToFile(someFile, item)
    callback();
}, //callback function
function () {...}
);
```

Comment: Thanks - could you also please let me know how to obtain the index of the iteratee within forEachSeries - I looked up online but couldn't find a clear example

Answer (score 2):

To explore more about async, you can use their method [each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

> Applies the function iteratee to each item in coll, in parallel. The
>   iteratee is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when
>   it has finished. If the iteratee passes an error to its callback, the
>   main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the
>   error.

Your code can be transformed to this:

```
var someFile = filePath;
async.series([
    function (cb) {
      async.each(someDataList, function (item, callback) {
        //call that executes out of sync
        writeToFile(someFile,item)

        // Execute internal callback for `async.each`
        callback()
      }, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          cb(error)
        } else {
          cb()
        }
      })
    }
  ],
//callback function
  function (err) {...
  }
);
```

But, of course, you need to take a look at your `writeToFile` function. 
If it is `sync` you need to wrap it in `try {} catch(e){}` construction and run internal `callback()` with error `callback(error)` in catch section.